# dispatch_async not working with background thread

Tags: multithreading, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I am having some heavy content to be loaded from data base and showed on to the Screen.
But at the same time there is a background task of 'plist to Data base' saving is going on.
Hence the UI gets stuck.

The code I am using as bellow,

For Data base fetch and UI update method

```
- (void)performBlockInBackground:(dispatch_block_t)taskBlock
                              completion:(dispatch_block_t)completionBlock
                            withPriotity:(dispatch_queue_priority_t)piority
{
    __block dispatch_block_t taskBlockRef = taskBlock;
    __block dispatch_block_t completionBlockRef = completionBlock;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(piority, 0), ^{

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(piority, 0), taskBlockRef);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), completionBlockRef);
    });
}
```

And I am calling the 'Plist to DB' method as

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(syncData) withObject:nil];
```

here the `taskBlock` is the heavy DB fetch and `completionBlock` is the UI Update.

If I call this method after some time (after the `syncData` method is done) then it updates smoothly. But if its not completed yet then the UI gets stuck.

It seems to be the issue of the thread deadlock but not clear on this

Please help !!

Comment: Why are you calling dispatch_sync() on the global queue?  What are you trying to achieve by making it synchronous?

Comment: I want the 'taskBlock' to be called like simple method. so that the data is prepared and take as time it requires to complete this block and then goes to the completion block which will run on the main thread for UI update.so basically its general method like call but with a block so its like Process in one block and when 'Done' update the UI in another.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `dispatch_sync()` when you're already in the right queue. You can call the block like so: `taskBlock()`.

```
- (void)performBlockInBackground:(dispatch_block_t)taskBlock
                    withPriority:(dispatch_queue_priority_t)priority
          completionOnMainThread:(dispatch_block_t)completionBlock
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0), ^{
    if (taskBlock) {
      taskBlock();
    }

    if (completionBlock) {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), completionBlock);
    }
  });
}
```

What happens is this:

- Immediately send the work to a background thread. Now we aren't blocking the calling thread or the main thread.
- If we have a `taskBlock`, do it now. `TaskBlock` is where you put your data fetch.
- `TaskBlock` finishes.
- If we have a `completionBlock`, send it to the main thread. `CompletionBlock` is where you update the UI.